# Generating a random key using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm

Tags: node.js, cryptography, aes

```
// import the path module
const path = require('node:path');
const crypto = require('crypto');

// get the public key certificate
const CRTpath = path.basename('./PublicKey.crt');

const GenKey = crypto.randomBytes(32);

// encode key to Base 64
const base64Key = Buffer.from(GenKey).toString('base64');

const OBJ = {
username: "xxx",
password: "xasadsd",
encryptKey: base64Key,
refreshToken: "false"
}

let jsonOBJ = JSON.stringify(OBJ);

function encryptString (plaintext, publicKeyFile) {
const publicKey = fs.readFileSync(publicKeyFile, "utf8");

    // publicEncrypt() method with its parameters 
    const encrypted = crypto.publicEncrypt( 
             publicKey, Buffer.from(plaintext)); 
    return encrypted; 

}

const encrypted = encryptString(jsonOBJ, CRTpath);

const baseEncrypted = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'utf8').toString("base64");
```

EDIT 1: I need to send a paylod as follows:

```
{
  requestID: "string", // this part is OK
  payload: "" // value of encrypted above
}
```

EDIT 2(specifications):

5.1.10. Steps to produce Authentication JSON in format requested
Steps

1. Generate a key (encryptKey) using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm and encode key to Base 64 String
2. Generate JSON corresponding to the “payload” attribute (username, password, encryptKey, refreshToken)
3. Encrypt JSON string from step 2 using MAURA Public Key and encode to Base 64 String. The public key encryption uses the standard RSA algorithm.

So far this is not working and returns a 404.

a) I am trying to use Nodejs Crypto module to generate a random key using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm.

b) I have to encrypt the key using a public key (.crt) files // This part i can deal with

c) Then send it as payload... // this part i can deal with

But however after numerous tries and reading docs, i could not wrap my head around the point a)...
I believe that i have wrongly done the ecryption before encoding to base64

Any help or leads will be most welcomed... many thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? A key for AES-256 is simply a sequence of 32 bytes, i.e. `GenKey` is an AES-256 key and `GenKey.toString('base64')` is the corresponding Base64 encoded key.

Comment: However, the encryption of the key seems to be missing in the code (`base64Key` is not used after its generation).

Comment: @Topaco, thank you for that quick response. The base64Key is the value of encryptKey in the OBJ object. More clarification in the post

Comment: So i am wondering how do i get to do this using the specification i mentionned in a) i.e :
Generate a key (encryptKey) using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm and encode key to Base 64 String using crypto module in NodeJs... am i missing something .... Again big thanks for any slightest leads...

Comment: I expect that `payload` hasn't been property encoded. Did you base64-encode payload? (You don't show that at any point.) Also, do you expect to receive 404 (rather than 400) when the parameters are wrong? You'll need to carefully check the spec. These kinds of protocols are often extremely precise, so we would need to know word-for-word what the spec says. (The phrase "random key using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm" doesn't really mean anything useful, so I'm betting the spec says something else.)

Comment: @RobNapier - Not at the time of my comment, changed in [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/78048724/3).

Comment: @RobNapier . Yes it is base64-encode, somehow truncated while formattin ^^. Unfortunately, it is the word-for-word from the specs. Thats was why i am confused. Also yes you are correct, the list of errors i expected is 400, but i am getting the 404 one

Comment: If you expect 400 and you get 404, then I would expect that your URL is incorrect. (But it is not unheard of for secured APIs to return 404 in a wide variety of cases to discourage snooping.)  OK, if the spec is literally "generate a random key using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm," I have no idea what to do with that. A random key is a random key. It does not matter how it is generated. But there are 1000 other details that you could be doing wrong. We cannot guess every detail of the spec from this description. You'll need to speak with the service provider.

Comment: (You could also point us to the complete spec, but as a rule, implementing a custom crypto protocol is more of a consulting problem than a Stack Overflow problem. SO is generally about questions others may also have in the future.)

Comment: Thanks @RobNapier for your insights :). Yes i believe i will need to cross check with the provider, in case there is something on their end. i did cross check all my steps, hence coming here to know where i was wrong... Will get back to this thread once i figure out.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to use Nodejs Crypto module to generate a random key using AES 256(AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding) algorithm.

This is not what you're doing, and not something you would generally ever do. (It's technically **possible** to directly use AES to generate a key, but for any reason you'd want to, there are better solutions.)

What you are doing (correctly, I believe) is generating a random AES key. An AES key is just a string of random bytes of a specific length. It isn't related to a mode (like ECB) or padding (like PKCS5). AES doesn't generate the key. It uses the key. Good AES keys are always random, or ["effectively random"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandomness) (which is a technical term with a precise definition) such as the output of PBKDF2. They have no internal structure at all. No headers. No flags. Nothing. Just a specified number of random bytes.

What you seem to have done here is make a random AES key, encrypted it using the server's public key, and sent it to the server. Public-private key encryption is slow. So you only use it to encrypt the AES key. AES is very fast. Now that you and the server share a key, you can quickly share encrypted data. What you've shown here is an extremely common approach.